# Передача значения переменной в другой модуль

Tags: python, python-3.x

Подскажите что делаю неправильно. Без использования потока и задержки времени значение передается нормально. А при исполнении mod1.py, через mod3.py вообще ничего не выводится.
Вообще хотел сделать что бы mod1.py работал самостоятельно, сохранял и обновлял значения переменной по времени, а через mod3.py когда необходимо мог получить данное значение для дальнейшего использования.
Заранее Спасибо!

mod1.py

```
import time
from threading import Thread
import mod2


def func(a, b):
    c = a + b
    return c


def func1():
    while True:
        var = funс(3, 2)
        mod2.var = var

        time.sleep(5)


thread1 = Thread(target=func)
thread1.start()
thread1.join()
```

mod2.py

```
var = 0
```

mod3.py

```
import mod1
import mod2

print(mod2.var)
```

Comment: зачем тут func1?

Comment: func1 вызывает func в определенный промежуток времени со своим набором данных,будет еще func2, она будет вызывать func в свой промежуток времени со своим набором данных, по этому использован Thread. Но суть в получении значения var из func1 в другой модуль.

Comment: Вообще значение обновляться должно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А разве не проще будет эту переменную сделать глобальной в mod1.py и брать её оттуда, соответственно.

Дополнено:
Все дело в том, что thread1.join() должен быть в самом конце кода.

Дополнено №2:
вот так должны выглядеть файлы

mod1.py

```
import time
from threading import Thread
import mod2


def add(a, b):
    c = a + b
    return c


def func1():
    while True:
        var = add(3, 2)
        mod2.var = var

        time.sleep(5)


thread1 = Thread(target=func1)
thread1.start()
```

mod3.py

```
import mod1
import mod2

while True:
    print(mod2.var)
    time.sleep(5)


mod1.thread1.join()
```

Comment: я думаю mod1 это главный файл, его лучше не подключать нигде, надо сделать файл например settings.py / config.py и там уже писать все глобальные переменные

Comment: я и пытаюсь так сделать, но видать сути не могу понять.

Comment: в общем цикл while в mod3.py можно и не писать (для наглядности сделал) . Главное join() писать в конце mod3.py, а не mod1.py